# Как в jQuery сделать, чтобы slideUp был на 100px?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как в jQuery сделать, чтобы slideUp был на 100px? У меня блок поначалу скрытый. Хочу чтобы при наведении мыши, он появился и открылся снизу вверх на 100 пикселей. Как это реализовать?

Comment: А возможно сначала задать блоку высоту в размере 100px с помощью css() метода а затем вызвать slideUp?

Comment: Возможно. Он у меня такой и есть. Просто он внутри другого блока с высотой 300px, и падает слайд именно с этой высоты и поднимается туда же @KryDos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причем тут **slideUp** к раскрытию блока? Снизу или сверху, но для раскрытия все равно **slideDown**. [Вот простой примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/G5PTd/).

Comment: @Deonis [так проще и лучше](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/G5PTd/1/)